# Invalid Summary on NSMutableArray

Tags: xcode, ipad, nsmutablearray, nskeyedarchiver, cgpoint

I would need some expert advice on how to solve this problem. I am doing some crude testing for a new app for the iPad.

I create a NSMutableArray (ballPath) in the viewDidLoad of my view controller (it is declared in my .h file) by loading a plist file created in another app.

```
ballPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];

NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"level_1" ofType:@"plist"];

ballPath = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
```

This array now contains a number of CGPoints (stored by the other app as NSValues and the archived).

[image]

I then draw the path (still in my viewDidLoad), which works fine, so the path should work fine.

When I later on want to read the array as a response to changes in acceleration, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. When I debug and look at my array it looks like this:

[image]

I test and replace the loaded array with this (also in viewDidLoad):

```
    ballPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)],
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 200.0)],
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 300.0)],
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 400.0)],
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(125.0, 450.0)],
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150.0, 500.0)],
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(300.0, 600.0)],
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(350.0, 550.0)],nil];
```

Then it works just fine!

[image]

What am I missing here????

I'm on Xcode 4.0.2 and my target is iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is deallocated at that point, so that there's some random memory where the array previously was.

`unarchiveObjectWithFile:` returns an autoreleased object, if you want to keep the array around, you need to retain it (or make it a retained property). The alloc-init two lines earlier is completely superfluous (and probably leaks memory), because you're never doing anything with the array you create there, it is *replaced* by the array you load from the bundle.

Comment: Thanks! I now create another array (arrayToLoad), load the archived file and then do ballPath = [arrayToLoad mutableCopy];